# Expected: End of Statement for Excel Formula

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel macro that formats a sheet down to its relevant data.
One of the columns I have taken (column C) has full names of individuals - and I am trying to put in a calculation that will pare the full name down to initials.

I have a calculation that works, if used by itself...but when I put it into the VBA macro, I get the "Expected: End of Statement".
The formula itself is:

```
=LEFT(C2)&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",C2)),MID(C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1,1),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1)),MID(C2,FIND(" ",C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1)+1,1),"")
```

The VBA code I have is:

```
Enter_Formulas() = "=LEFT(C2)&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",C2)),MID(C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1,1),"")&IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(" ",C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1)),MID(C2,FIND(" ",C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1)+1,1),"")"
```

I get the End of Statement error at the first `FIND` part above, I believe because the ", followed by a space seems to signal the end of the statement - how do I overcome this?  Or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: `" "` should be `"" ""` basically double all `"`

Comment: Scott, thank you so much, that resolved it!
I'm no programmer, so I appreciate all of the help that everyone provides in these forums!!!